# binding city to an AutoSuggestBox

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I am trying to learn MVVVM, by doing a weather application, using a Udemy course as a reference, the Bing Maps Api, and the OpenWeather API.

I am trying to bind the city with the text of the AutoSuggestBox of my xaml

I have done the WeatherVM and bind it to the view, as a page resource
I also did a quick Method that gets me the City and the Country code, where I am (Using the Bing Maps api)
I Called the method from the MainPage.cs, only to see if it works, and it work fine I get the City and Country Code as expected

WeatherVM

```
        public OpenWeather OpenWeather { get; set; }

        private Task<string> _city;

        public Task<string> city {
            get { return _city; }
            set {
                _city = value;
                GetLocationData();
            }
        }

        public WeatherVM() {
            OpenWeather = new OpenWeather();
        }

        private async void GetLocationData() {
            var cityData = await MapLocator.GetCityData();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
    x:Class="MVVM_Example.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MVVM_Example"
    xmlns:vm="using:MVVM_Example.ViewModel"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <vm:WeatherVM x:Key="vm" />
    </Page.Resources>


    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <AutoSuggestBox Margin="40" QueryIcon="Find"
                        PlaceholderText="Search" 
                        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=city, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I expect "Orlando" to appear in my AutoSuggestBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Binding, you need to set the DataContext of the page to be an instance of your binding source class instead of set the page.Resource. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:WeatherVM x:Name="viewModelInDataContext"/>
</Page.DataContext>


<Grid>
    <AutoSuggestBox Margin="40" QueryIcon="Find"
                    PlaceholderText="Search" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=city, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

In code-behind, suppose you need to assign a value to the city.

```
this.viewModelInDataContext.city = "Orlando";
```

**Update**:

The ViewModel you showed has some issues. First, you need to assign a value to the cityData property, if not, the text of AutoSuggestBox which bound with the cityData will always display empty. Second, you need to implement INotifyChanged in WeatherVM. When your cityData changes, the text of the AutoSuggestBox will change. Third, do not set the property type to asynchronous like Task, this will affect the display, it's better to set string cityData.

```
public class WeatherVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WeatherVM(){
        GetData();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string _cityData;
    public string cityData
    {
        get
        {
            return _cityData;
        }
        set
        {
             _cityData = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private async void GetData() 
    { 
        cityData = await MapLocator.GetCityData(); 
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I set the context already <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"> becouse I am using MVVM, I am not suppose to have anything in the code behind. That is wha my teacher told me

Comment: Sorry for my omission. The xaml you set is correct, but about code-behind has the following questions. First, you need to assign a value to the city property, if not, the text of AutoSuggestBox will always display empty. You should set x:name instead of x:key, So that you can use it in .cs and assign it like: `this.vm.city = ...;`  Second, you need to implement INotifyChanged in WeatherVM. When your city changes, the text of the AutoSuggestBox  will change. Third, do not set the property type to asynchronous like Task<string>, this will affect the display, it's better to set `string city`.

Comment: I Implemented the INotifyChanged in WeatherVM and added this to the AutoSuggestBox  `Text="{Binding Path=cityData}` and in my weatherVM, I have  `public string cityData {
            get { return _cityData; }
            set {
                _cityData = value;
                GetLocationData();
            }
        }` I am not suppose to have anything in the code behind. in MVVM, the View doesn't have to know where the data came from, My method `GetLocation` returns me the city and the country code

Comment: in this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm2tOtr8ReM&t=283s he doesn't have any code in the code behind. Of course, he is using a framework, but I am doing it manually

Comment: The video you provided is not a UWP tutorial. The meaning of the reference is not great. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm) to learn about MVVM. In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can reproduce this issue? Because in my understanding, I don't see you assign a value to your cityData. The cityData remains empty, so "Orlando" can't appear in the AutoSuggestBox.

Comment: Hello how are you doing today?. I have the method `GetCityData`, that returns me the city and the country code, and I know that this method works because I tested it on the MainPge.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuPWj2VdUNuhvZUwcGXANtB7HS8_LQ?e=96YgTz``
and then I am doing  `Text="{Binding Path=cityData, Mode=TwoWay}"` IN MY AutoBox

Comment: OK, when the method returns you the city and the country code, do you have any operations afterwards? In this method, I can only see that you get the data, and don't see that you assign a value to the property of the cityData which bound with Text. In order to solve the problem better, can you provide a simple sample for use to reproduce?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is, current me if I am wrong but since I don't hace a class, to store this data, it will not work because the binding would get the data of the model. If I don't have a class to capture the data, how can it work. correct

Comment: Ok I added a class named Location, that will have two properties: city and country code, but still nothing. I have one example https://github.com/eduardoagr/uwpMVVM where I don't have anything in my code behind, But this example was made with accuWeatherAPI and now I am using the OpenWather. I already have my city and country code, but when I call the method in the WeatheVM and put a breakpoint nothing happens, no bindind nothing

Comment: Also what you were saying, I never assign my value to the textbox. So I did `private string _cityData;

        public string cityData {
            get { return _cityData; }
            set {
                _cityData = value;
                GetData();
            }
        }

        private async void GetData() {
            cityData = await MapLocator.GetCityData();
        }`

Comment: The link you shared shows "404", have you deleted or set it private? In addition, I suggest you can put the GetData() method in the WeatherVM() like `public WeatherVM(){ GetData(); } public string cityData { get { return _cityData; } set { _cityData = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }` . In this case, when you use WeatherVM first time, it will assign the value to cityData directly. And you need to be sure the value returned by `MapLocator.GetCityData()` is also of type string.

Comment: Btw sometimes visual studio tell me "Cannot resolve WeatherVM" is annoying, but works

Comment: I sorted out our reply and updated it with the answer. If you feel that this helps you and solves your problem, you can mark it.